# Need to insert picklist values from one field to other picklist field

Tags: picklist, metadata-api, standard-objects

I need to insert the picklist values from one picklist field to Other.Is there any way to extract/export all the picklist values and import it into other one.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script to run anonymously in workbench if its just the 1 time activity. And it will reduce manual work and errors

```
 List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
 for(Account obj: [Select Field1__c, Field2__c from Account Where Field1__c != NULL] ) {
     obj.Field2__c = obj.Field1__c;
     accUpdateList.add(obj);
 }

 if(accUpdateList.size() > 0){
     update accUpdateList;
 }
```

If the records are more then you can go for a batch class if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using Force.com IDE you can do that. Just copy and paste the values values from one Picklist to the Other in the `<object name>.object` file and save it.